# Recommended steps for securing a lost phone

Tags: lost-phone

According to Android Device Manager you have several options when it comes to a lost or stolen phone.

However it's not clear to me if you are supposed to select just one of them (lock your phone or erase the phone's data for example) or you can select both.

If you select one, there's no doubt about the expected behavior. 
However, it's not clear what to expect if one first selects erase phone's data, and then selects lock the phone, or viceversa. Does the second option interrupt the first one? Or do they both remain active?

To complicate things a little more, what would happen, if additionally, you changed your google password in the process? In a logical attempt to prevent any further unauthorized access to any of your google products ...

So, in the simpler case of just telling ADM to delete everything, what would happen if:

1. you changed the google password "before" confirming the deletion process? Would a password change at this stage interfere with google's ability to contact the phone before it had a chance to receive the deletion trigger?
2. you changed the google password "after" confirming the deletion process?
   Would a password change at this stage interfere with google's ability to contact the phone before it had a chance to receive the deletion trigger?

If anyone has had any experience with ADM I'll appreciate your feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: This **may** be better served at Android.SE. If you don't get useful answers here, flag it for migration and I'll send it over.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting "Erase phone's data" , the phone wipes off the data as soon as it gets spotted so selecting "Lock the phone" won't take effect.

And regarding the password changing, I once erased my phone and after a day changed my google password. The password was changed without any issue.

Comment: If the phone is offline when you issue the erase phone data, the order is actually queued somewhere. If you give it another order, it may very well replace the pending order with the new one (or not). It doesn't say anything, anywhere, about which one google honors first. Your second answer, regarding the password change, has also nothing to do with what I asked. I'm asking if a password change before the phone is actually contacted/erased would interfere in google's ability to contact it/delete it afterwards.

Comment: My second answer is the reply to your question in Point  2

`you changed the google password "after" confirming the deletion process? Would a password change at this stage interfere with google's ability to contact the phone before it had a chance to receive the deletion trigger?`

Comment: The scenario refers to "After" confirming the deletion process and "Before" the phone has been yet contacted (because it was offline). Otherwise the question "Would a password change at this stage interfere with google's ability to contact the phone before it had a chance to receive the deletion trigger?" would make no sense, since the phone had already been contacted. Thanks for sharing your experience anyways.

Comment: I understood your scenario and answered for the same. I had changed my password before the phone was contacted and was able to do so.